# Using MailEnvelope VBA on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a protected sheet from which I want to send a certain selection in a MailEnvelope via VBA. The password breach isn't the issue. However, I'm trying to get the sheet to be protected afterwards within the same macro and that's what I cannot figure out how.

This is my VBA so far:

```
Sub SEND_()

Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim wspword As String
Dim auditdate As String
Dim audittime As String

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set tws = twb.Worksheets(8)

auditdate = Range("D8").Text
audittime = Range("D10").Text
wspword = "Hello123"

tws.Unprotect (wspword)

Range("B4:H48").Select

  ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "use this field to add message"
    .Item.To = ""
    .Item.Subject = "Results | " & audittime & " on " & auditdate
  End With
  

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to get in the password afterwards without using a second macro?

If I add

```
tws.Protect (wspword)
```

at the end, I get an error saying:

Run-time error '1004': 
Method 'Protect' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Side note, remove the parentheses. Also remove them in `tws.Unprotect (wspword)`.

Comment: If I remove the parentheses in the `tws.Protect wspword` and `tws.Protect wspword` (which I've added at the very end of the VBA), I get another error: "A sheet in the workbook you are trying to save is password protected. Password protected sheets cannot be saved in a Web Page. To save this file as a Web Page, you must remove the password."  So it seems the password gets placed before the user can click on "Send this selection" in the MailEnvelope pop-up.